# Функция exec не видит переменную python

Tags: python

День добрый, необходимо создавать множество кнопок, проблема в том, что без возведения в функцию всё работает отлично, но как только я возвожу в функцию:

```
NameError: name 'id_button_01' is not defined
```

```
M = {1: '01', 2: 'M', 4: 0}


def func(E):
    exec(f"id_button_{E} = tk.Button(window, image=M_img, command=pressed(M[4], M[2], id_button_{E}))")
    exec(f"id_button_{E}.place(x=0, y=0)")


func(M[1])
```

Помогите, в чём проблема?
Или как можно написать данную функцию без exec?
Сильно не пинайте, совсем ещё мал и неопытен. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Что на счет [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module) топика?

Comment: @Shamus Rezol, Дело в том, что у меня проблема именно с заданием аргумента к другой функции, аргументом является объект id_button_01(сама кнопка), и когда exec находится в def, этот аргумент не ищется, хотя без функции - без проблем.
В топике используются методы, которые я в следующей функции использую, с ними никаких проблем нет, тут же не получится задать глобальной переменной, так как она всё равно будет ссылаться на это же имя.

Comment: переменные то локальные получаются, НЕ пишите так, это жесть.

Comment: Кажется кому-то надо научиться пользоваться массивами и/или словарями.

Comment: Думаю, тут ` command=pressed(M[4], M[2], id_button_{E}))` потерялась лямбда, что и вызвала бы `pressed` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Или как можно написать данную функцию без exec?

Используйте словарь.

Например:

```
M = {1: '01', 2: 'M', 4: 0}
id_button = dict()

def func(E):
    id_button[E] = tk.Button(window, image=M_img, command=pressed(M[4], M[2], id_button[E]))
    id_button[E].place(x=0, y=0)

func(M[1])
```

Тогда все кнопки, добавленные через `func`, можно будет получить из словаря `id_button`

Comment: Идеально гениальный в своей простоте способ. Спасибо

Comment: @Be3yBuu, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникала не из-за `exec` а по причине того что в конструктор кнопки передавалась еще не инициализированная переменная `id_button_N`, при разбитии на 2 комманды все работает. Так же я использовал `лямбду` для инициализации `command`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

M = {1: '01', 2: 'M', 4: 0}
window = tk.Tk()
M_img=None

def pressed(a,b,c):
  mb.showinfo(title="'"+str(a)+"'", message=b)

def func(E):
  exec(f"""id_button_{E} = tk.Button(window, image=M_img)
id_button_{E}['command'] = lambda:pressed(M[4], M[2], id_button_{E})""",
  globals())
  
  exec(f"id_button_{E}.place(x=0, y=0)", globals())


func(M[1])

window.mainloop()
```

Вот небольшой пример как передавать внутрь `exec` переменные:

```
N = 100;
ns_globals = {'N':N}
ns_locals = {'K': 20}
exec('N += K\nprint("№1", N)', ns_globals, ns_locals)
print('№2', N)
exec('N += N', globals())
print("№3", N)
```

выведет:

```
№1 120
№2 100
№3 200
```

exec(obj[, globals[, locals]])-> None

**obj** : Строка кода, либо объект кода. Поддерживается ввод данных из файлов (считываются до EOF). Если передана строка, она разбирается в набор инструкций, который потом исполняется (если отсутствуют синтаксические ошибки). Если передан объект кода, то он исполняется.

**globals** : Ожидается dict. Словарь глобального пространства, относительно которого следует исполнить код. Если **locals** не передан, будет использован **globals**. Если словарь не имеет значения по ключу `__builtins__`, на это место вставляется ссылка на значение аналогичного атрибута глобального пространства. Модифицировав `__builtins__` словаря передаваемого в функцию, вы можете контролировать, какие какие из встроенных инструментов будут доступны коду.

**locals** : Ожидается объект-отображение (например, dict). Локальное пространство, в котором следует исполнить код.

Функциям **exec()** и **eval()** можно передавать результаты функций **globals()** и **locals()**.

Comment: Возьму на заметку, но вариант со словарями кажется более практичным. Спасибо.

Comment: Разумеется, я бы тоже предпочел со словарями, просто отвечал на вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что exec не может влиять на глобальные переменные. Попробуйте

```
M = {1: '01', 2: 'M', 4: 0}


def func(E):
    exec(f"id_button_{E}") = tk.Button(window, image=M_img, command=pressed(M[4], M[2], id_button_{E}))
    exec(f"id_button_{E}").place(x=0, y=0)


func(M[1])
```

https://www.codepile.net/pile/LVk5ryNQ

Comment: exec может влиять на глобальные переменные, просто в функции нет глобальной переменной, если вывести за пределы функции, то всё работает. Так что ваш вариант не подходит